# Blockchain.info Receive Payments API problem

Tags: transactions, payment, api, blockchain.info

I am building a little online app to accept bitcoin payments in my website. I have a blockchain.info wallet and I am following their Receive Payments Api, which can be visited here: http://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

The monetary part works great, but the HTTP Callback Notification does not take place and my online store is not notified of the payment. However, the TEST callback does work.

I think it is a problem on his application.

- Has anyone implemented the "Receive Money API" successfully?
- Is there any other alternative for received instant payment notifications?
  (To several different addresses)

A friend of mine reports the same issue. We need a little help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using generating addresses with the anonymous flag true or false?

Comment: Hi Ben :-) I am generating addresses with the anonymous flag to false. The "fire test callback" works great, but when I actually send bitcoins, the http notification is not sent. Any ideas?

Comment: So, if I send bitcoins to the forward address, the payment is sent to my real address successfully. But the notification is not set :-(

Comment: Hi Ben. Could you please help me out? I would really appreciate since I can't go beyond the documentation. Test callback works ok, bitcoins are forwarded to the real addres but the notification is not sent from your Java App. I am sure about this because I am logging all queries and have access to the apache2 access logs.

Comment: Perhaps you have a list of blacklisted servers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is working now! Issue closed. Great service provided by BlockChain.

Comment: Well, can you tell us what was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: After I reported the issue via email/this post, Blockchain.info solved it and now everything works fine.

Comment: Nice that it is working, but i have a problem to setup the callback, i want this service in virtuemart, can you please explain me how to do, i wil pay for it to get it working, anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi John. You have to set up a forward address in the "Developers" -> "Receive Payments API" section of Blochkchain.info. By doing that, you provide them with an URL to be called every time a payment is received. Data arrives via $_GET.

Comment: Or examining any given address with the Block Explorer API. This is much easier if you can set up a cron job.

Comment: Hi. Just use this: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api. Send an http request to the single address URI and parse the JSON your application receives.